# How to know what's a stub?

Tags: assembly, rmi, mips, corba, stub

Does stub always mean the same thing when you write programs?

> "Stubs provide replacement implementations for objects, methods, or
>   functions in order to remove external dependencies. Stubs are
>   typically used during unit and component testing. If you're trying to
>   write a unit test and need to replace a simple call to a database,
>   external libraries (e.g., file I/O) or other system API, stubbing
>   might be perfectly suited for your needs."

I thought stub and skeleton were only in CORBA but here there's a stub and is that the same thing/concept? A coiincidence or a connection when the word "stub" appears in rather different programming models (RMI and MIPS assmebly are 2 rather different) both have the concept / thing called "stub" and I also know for RMI / CORBA there's something called the skeleton but it's also possible to have a stub without a skeleton or what?

For instance when main is translated to assembly it's called a stud here and is there a connection to that stub and skeleton are used in network programming such as CORBA or is it no connection despite both are called stub?

```
movia r8,stub # source
movia r9,0x800020 # destination
ldw r10,0(r8) # read
stw r10,0(r9) # write
ldw r10,4(r8) # read part 2
stw r10,4(r9) # write
ldw r10,8(r8) # read jump
stw r10,8(r9) # write
... # initialize others
```

Is the code above an exmple of a stub? If so, what would be a skeleton or is that not applicable?

Thanks for info.

Comment: It is a very generic programming term.  Just look at the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub

Comment: I don't know if there's a real definition, but that thing above smells like a stub to me. A synonym could be a wrapper.

Comment: a stub is a generic term, not specific to any language or platform or environment.  The generic definition you quoted pretty much covers it, for testing purposes or even for distribution of something you can use a stub to close off some dangling interface that you are not really using or want to fake out so it wont interfere, or as in the definition you quoted test the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORBA and RMI stub is a quite specific object that locally represents a certain remote object. This object exists on server side and the stub exists on a client side. The stub implements the same interface (has same working methods), forwarding all calls to the remote object, also receiving returned results and exceptions. Stub class is normally often automatically generated.

Stub in general has a different meaning (something that is only half finished, often just enough to make the code to compile but not to run properly).